# Mysql querys over multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, performance

This code  pulls together a list of members then lists all the items they have added in a category and then outputs all this information to a table.

Here's the 3 table layouts:

```
Members
member_id - fname - lname - etc.

Items
member_id - item_id - etc.

Categories
name - etc.
```

And the current code which takes FOREVER to load:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY lname, fname ASC"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <? echo('Name'); ?>
        <? echo $rows[fname];?> <? echo $rows[lname];?> 

    <? $sql2="SELECT * FROM leadtypes ORDER BY name ASC"; 
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
    while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ ?>

        <? echo $rows2[name];?>
        <? echo(': '); ?>

        <? $sql4="SELECT lead_id FROM leads WHERE member_id='$rows[member_id]' AND type='$rows2[name]' ORDER BY name ASC"; 
        $result4=mysql_query($sql4);
        $num4 = mysql_num_rows($result4); ?>

        <? echo $num4;?>

    <? } ?>
<? } ?>`
```

I know I shouldn't query * but this is a very stripped down piece of code on a test server. I would be grateful If somebody knows a good way of combining all this together to speed up the system.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo The code was written years ago. Sorry, I haven't had any experience with MySQLi yet either

Comment: @h2ooooooo Could anyone else help? I have shamefully never used a JOIN before :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = SELECT A.lead_id,B.name,C.fname,C.lname 
       FROM leads A
       JOIN leadtypes B ON A.type = B.name 
       JOIN members C ON A.member_id = C.member_id
```

You can echo this as

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
  echo $row['name'];
  echo $row['fname'];
}
```

Have a look at these links

1. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Try doing one join instead of multiple queries. For example,

`SELECT lt.*, l.lead_id FROM leadtypes lt, leads l WHERE l.member_id=lt.member_id AND l.type=lt.name ORDER BY l.name ASC`

If that one query is still slow then it means you need to add indices on your tables.